# PHP Dismantling array for database inserts

Tags: php, arrays, database

I am really stuck on dismantling an array

```
$data = file('ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/2018/StatesCONUS.Heating.txt');
for ($h = 3; $h <= $ab; $h++) {
  $o = explode("|", $dataish[$h]);
  print_r($o);
}
```

This creates something like the below:

```
Array (
   [0] => Region
   [1] => 20180101
   [2] => 20180102
   ...
   [186] => 20180705
)
Array(
   [0] => AL
   [1] => 42
   [2] => 41
   ...
   [186] => 0
)
```

It then continues for all states through to WY.

I am trying to dismantle the arrays so they are their own variables. I would like to have region as one variable, such as $region and AL as another such as $al, through to $wy. I cannot figure out how to dismantle it.

My end goal is to loop through everything and for each date insert the value for every state. I would be creating a database with rows as the number of days in the year so far by 48 states

```
|Date    |AL| ... |WY|
|20180101|42| ... |56|
|........|..| ... |..|
|20180705|..| ... |..|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to know, for people who want to answer this, that the file can actually be downloaded. The FTP link works.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is hosted by a US government department

Comment: So what is the database table definition you want to insert into?

Comment: I am amateur to this, I was trying to sort out how I could manipulate the array to ensure it was possible to get the format I needed before creating the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the data more usable, rather than trying to extract it to separate variables, it may be better to extract it to an array of data for each region which the various columns associated with the relevant dates.

So first get the headers from the 4th row (into `$headers`) and then use `array_combine` to take the data from each row with these headers...

```
$data = file('ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/2018/StatesCONUS.Heating.txt');
$rows = count($data);

$headers = explode("|", $data[3]);
array_shift($headers);
$output = [];
for ($h = 4; $h < $rows; $h++) {
    $row = explode("|", $data[$h]);
    $region = $row[0];
    array_shift($row);
    $output[$region] = array_combine($headers, $row);

}
print_r($output);
```

This gives the output in the format...

```
Array
(
    [AL] => Array
        (
            [20180101] => 42
            [20180102] => 41
            [20180103] => 35
            [20180104] => 37
            [20180105] => 36
            [20180106] => 33
            [20180107] => 29
```

You can then loop over this array and insert the data into the database using a couple of foreach loops.

Comment: This is really promising. I am going to explore how to insert with this. Not sure how I will get but I really like how you have this output. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
// get data
$data = file('ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/2018/StatesCONUS.Heating.txt');

// put data in local variables
for ($i = 3; $i < count($data); $i++) {
  $line = explode("|", $data[$i]);
  $name = array_shift($line);
  ${$name} = $line;
}

// show all global variables (just to check the result)
echo '<pre>';
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo '</pre>';
```

There's not much to explain since the code looks almost identical to yours. The only difference is that I get the variable name from the first value in the array using `array_shift` and the use a variable variable (no typo!) to make it a global/local variable, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

You could put `strtolower()` around `$name` if you only want lower case variables.